# Как получить последние 5 постов вк?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Официальный метод vk api get.wall не отдает записи пользователей в группе с открытой стеной.

Внимание вопрос: как получить список последних 5 постов пользователей в открытой группе?

Comment: "Официальный метод vk api get.wall не отдает записи пользователей в группе с открытой стеной." --- а? что? чёйта?

Comment: Проверил, wall.get всё отлично отдаёт

Comment: andreymal, ВК не отдает юзерские посты в открытом паблике. Только посты группы.

Comment: @БорисК о чём речь? В пабликах в принципе не бывает юзерских постов.

Answer (score 0):

https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

> filter:  suggests — предложенные записи на стене сообщества (доступно
> только при вызове с передачей access_token); postponed — отложенные
> записи (доступно только при вызове с передачей access_token); owner —
> записи владельца стены; others — записи не от владельца стены; all —
> все записи на стене (owner + others).